# More than two distinct factorizations?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

So we all know about 6 and its two factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$. Can an integer have more than two factorizations in some non-UFD? And if so, can it be a squarefree semiprime like 6 or does it have to be a multiple of some square?

Comment: If $6$ has two factorizations, then $6^2$ has...

Comment: But how are you sure you're coming up with genuinely distinct factorizations?

Comment: Noting distinct factorizations are distinct is pretty straightforward.